# Apply a filter with CSS to change colors of a picture

Tags: css, filter

In this CodePen, a filter is used to turn a blue color into a grey color:

```
filter: grayscale(100%);
```

How can I change the color to blue/red/green using css filters?

https://codepen.io/wiseoldman/pen/RVRgyB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use filter `hue-rotate(*x*deg)` to change the colors, here I have attached code.

```css
body {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0;
}
body div {
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}

form#smileys input[type="radio"] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: border .2s ease;
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
          filter: grayscale(100%);
  margin: 0 5px;
  transition: all .2s ease;
}
form#smileys input[type="radio"]:focus {
  
  outline: 0;
}
form#smileys input[type="radio"].happy:hover,form#smileys input[type="radio"].happy:checked{
  -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(300deg);
          filter: hue-rotate(300deg);
}
form#smileys input[type="radio"].happy {
  background: url("https://res.cloudinary.com/turdlife/image/upload/v1492864443/happy_ampvnc.svg") center;
  background-size: cover;
}
form#smileys input[type="radio"].neutral:hover,form#smileys input[type="radio"].neutral:checked{
  -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(10deg);
          filter: hue-rotate(10deg);
}
form#smileys input[type="radio"].neutral {
  background: url("https://res.cloudinary.com/turdlife/image/upload/v1492864443/neutral_t3q8hz.svg") center;
  background-size: cover;
}
form#smileys input[type="radio"].sad:hover,form#smileys input[type="radio"].sad:checked{
  -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(160deg);
          filter: hue-rotate(160deg);
}
form#smileys input[type="radio"].sad {
  background: url("https://res.cloudinary.com/turdlife/image/upload/v1492864443/sad_bj1tuj.svg") center;
  background-size: cover;
}

.mtt {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 20px;
  color: #999;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.mtt span {
  color: #e74c3c;
}
.mtt:hover {
  color: #666;
}
.mtt:hover span {
  color: #c0392b;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="smileys">
 <input type="radio" name="smiley" value="sad" class="sad">
 <input type="radio" name="smiley" value="neutral" class="neutral">
 <input type="radio" name="smiley" value="happy" class="happy" checked="checked">
 <div>It looks like you're feeling <span id="result">happy</span> today..</div>
</form>

<a class="mtt" href="https://morningtrain.dk" target="_blank">
 With <span>♥</span> from Morning Train
</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I've been looking for.

Comment: @toms You're welcome, please accept the solution, if this is exactly what you have been looking for.

Answer (score 13):

### Nice & Simple With CSS [Filters](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/filter/)

Very easy when using the `hue-rotate()` filter.

Make your images red, which has a hue value of 0, then use a [hue chart](https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_hsl.asp) to grab the colours you require for the hue rotation.

Use the `filter:grayscale(1)` to set all images to grey, then on hover, set the grayscale to 0 and adjust the colour values.

[image]

```css
.colorRed,.colorBlue, .colorGreen {filter:grayscale(1);}
.colorRed:hover,.colorBlue:hover, .colorGreen:hover {filter:grayscale(0);}
.colorRed img:hover {filter:hue-rotate(0deg);}
.colorBlue img:hover {filter:hue-rotate(215deg);}
.colorGreen img:hover {filter:hue-rotate(100deg);}
```

```html
<span class="colorGreen"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/ZbOHifU.png" width="100px";></span>
<span class="colorBlue"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/msjbI0M.png" width="100px";></span>
<span class="colorRed"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/tycbKyW.png" width="100px";></span>
<div class="colorRed"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/A7A9wec.jpg" width="500px";></div>
<div class="colorBlue"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/A7A9wec.jpg" width="500px";></div>
<div class="colorGreen"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/A7A9wec.jpg" width="500px";></div>
```

Comment: My pleasure. If it answers your question, don't forget to flag it as an answer with the tick box. And if you need any other help, just let me know :)

Comment: And I should have mentioned, I decided not to change your oringal code, but rather show it used in another way, showing the technique of starting of with a red colour to help get your other colours values and how you can set all to grey before one is chosen. This could then be adapted to your current code.

Answer (score 0):

there is a filter called `hue-rotate` for similar thing
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter

why do you want to use filter for that you can directly use `color` or `background-color` properties for this.